# Как объяснить постановку запятой

Tags: пунктуация

Это ваш порядок, и его менять нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Это сложносочиненное предложение, две основы: "это порядок" и "менять нельзя".

Comment: поймали утибоземоя он был здоровенький но вдруг вздохнул и помер от избытка сюсюк ©